# Tiling an orthogonal polygon with squares

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, tiling

Given an orthogonal polygon (a polygon whose sides are parallel to the axes), I want to find the smallest set of interior-disjoint squares, whose union equals the polygon.

I found several references to slightly different problems, such as:

- *Covering* an orthogonal polygon with squares - similar to my problem, but the covering squares are allowed to overlap. This problem has a polynomial solution ([Aupperle, Conn, Keil and O'Rourke, 1988](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/Papers/ConnJORsquares.pdf);  [Bar-Yehuda and Ben-Hanoch, 1996](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S021819599600006X)).
- Tiling/decomposing/partitioning an orthogonal polygon to *rectangles*. This problem has a polynomial solution ([Keil, 2000](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/B978-044482537-7/50012-7); [Eppstein, 2009](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-11409-0_1)).
- *Covering* an orthogonal polygon with *rectangles* - this problem is known to be NP-complete ([Culberson and Reckhow, 1988](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/sfcs.1988.21976)).

I am looking for an algorithm for minimal *tiling* with *squares*.

Comment: mmm I can imagine this being NP-hard. I'll try to formulate something.

Comment: The minimization version with holes allowed is NP-Hard, but for simply-connected orthogonal polygons (i.e. without holes) it has a polynomial algorithm. However, if in your problem the sizes are integer and you really mean a minimal cover and not a minimum cover, then in this case a polynomial algorithm is possible.

Comment: Mmm, I need a proof that a the minimum squares will be rationally positioned and have rational sizes; or even more, that if the input is integer-sized and integer-positioned, then the minimum squares will be as well (to reduce it to SAT). Intuitively, I conjecture that this is true, do you have any ideas to prove it?

Comment: @MahmoudAlimohamadi: can you provide the titles/authors of the paper(s) where the problem of *tiling* rectilinear polygons (with or without holes) with squares is studied (and solved).

Comment: @RealzSlaw this is a good question, I will think about it.

Comment: @Vor Sorry, I just learned they allow overlapping squares. It wasn't apparent from its abstract, or I read it carelessly.

Comment: think the way to go on this is with [bin packing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) literature. there is stuff that is close such as packing rectangles in rectangles etc....

Comment: btw, I assumed you meant minim*um* instead of minim*al*.

Comment: Followup question: [How to prove that the minimum square partition of a 3X2 rectangle has 3 squares](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16809/2755).

Comment: btw, if you change the requirement to *integer-sized squares*, then you can be sure it is in $NP$, and thus at least NP-complete, instead of just NP-hard. As it is now, I am unsure if the minimum tiling/partition would even be rational. And even if it would be rational (or if you change the question to only allow for rational square answers), one would have to prove bounds on the sizes of the rationals. continued ...

Comment: In [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16809/2755) followup question, Yuval's answer mentions that there is a "classical result of Dehn shows that if an $h\times w$ rectangle can be tiled by squares then $\frac h w$ is rational", but then you'd have to extend this result to orthogonal polygons, *and* bound the sizes of the rationals (they might be exponentially sized?). However, the weaker question of asking for *integer-sized squares* does away with all these proof requirements.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will try to show this problem is NP-hard, by reduction from $\text{Planar-}3\text{-SAT}$.

---

## Reduction from $\text{Planar-}3\text{-SAT}$

### Some basic Gadgets

Gadgets are internal configurations of geometry that will allow us to construct gates for use in a circuit, to which we will reduce $\text{Planar-}3\text{-SAT}$.

#### **4X3-gadget**

This gadget has two valid **minimal-square-partition-states**:

[image]
       
[image]
       
[image]

<sup><sup>**Left**A **4X3-gadget**.**Middle and right:**Two possible **minimal-square-partition-states**.</sup></sup>

#### **5X4-gadget**

This gadget, is exactly like a **4X3-gadget**, just with larger dimensions.

[image]
       
[image]
       
[image]

<sup><sup>**Left**A **5X4-gadget**.**Middle and right:**Two possible **minimal-square-partition-states**.</sup></sup>

#### **endpoint-gadget**

An **endpoint-gadget** *is* a **5X4-gadget**. It is frequently used as an endpoint/pin of a **gate**. One of the two states of an endpoint can be valued as true, and the other false. An endpoint marks the two ends, one as $T$ and the other as $F$. **The end that is covered by the large square is the value of the endpoint.**

[image]

<sup><sup>**Left:** Wireframe of **endpoint-gadget**. **Center:**True-valued endpoint. **Right:** False-valued endpoint.</sup></sup>

#### **i-wire gadget**

An **i-wire gadget** is short for **implication wire**.

**Rules:**

- An **i-wire gadget** consists of a odd-length rectangle of a length of more than $2$ and a width of $2$.
- An **i-wire gadget** can have $3$ **minimal-square-partition-states**, pushed from one side, the other, or neither; an **i-wire** in this third state shall be called **locally unconstrainted**.

Example:

[image]

<sup><sup>**Figure 7:** An **i-wire gadget** of length $7$, and width $2$.</sup></sup>

Here is how it is used:

[image]          [image]

<sup><sup>**Figure 8,9**, **Left:** wireframe **i-wire across** two **endpoints**. **Right:** Union.</sup></sup>

Now, if one **endpoint** is in the right state, it forces the other **endpoint** into a pushed-position. Example:

[image]         [image]

<sup><sup>**Left:** Square partition diagram; left switch is down, "pushes" all the squares down the **i-wire** and finally, pushes the other switch (**endpoint**). **Right:** Square partition diagram; left **endpoint** is full, "pushes" all the squares down the **i-wire**, and forces the **endpoint** on left to be "up".</sup></sup>

This is essentially a logical implication. Consider "down" to be true, then we have $A \implies \neg B$. We can also do $A \implies B$ by simply flipping the endpoint on the right.

However, this leaves the unconstrainted case:

[image]

If we combine two **i-wires**, we can get a two-way implication, essentially a boolean (in)equality:

[image]
       
[image]

So, two **i-wires** can carry a full equality relationship, much like a circuit - in fact, it *is* a circuit. We will use these pairs to construct a usable **wire**.

Each **i-wire gadget** contributes $\frac{l-1}{2}+2$ partition-squares to the **minimal-square-partition**, save for the shared-corners with other gadgets.

**i-wires** can be oriented as needed.

### **wire**

A **wire** consists a pair of **i-wires** that are connected to the same **gates** at each endpoint.

- The **i-wires** are colored red and green.
- The pair must be separated by $3$ spaces (convention).
- Each gate pin will have a green and red contact; a wire must correctly connect.
- ***Invariant rule:*** one **i-wire** be pushed in the opposite direction of the other **i-wire**, each gate assumes this, and makes certain of this (unless otherwise noted).
- Since each wire contains a two-way implication, it carries the values from gate to gate like a wire in a circuit.
- **Every *wire* must be connected to a gate at both ends.**. Failing this can ruin the assumptions of some gates that I describe, and the invariant rule above; however, gates that have **endpoints** *across the leads* are safe - you can connect stray wires to these **endpoints** without worrying about it ruining the gate.
- **wires** must be of odd-length, *including* the leads to any circuit it connects to; however I will describe an **odd-skip-gate** below that allows an even-lengthed wire to become odd-lengthed.

**Pictures**:

[image]

<sup><sup>**Above:** A **wire**.</sup></sup>

[image]        [image]

<sup><sup>**Left and right:** Two possible **minimal-square-partition-states** of a **wire**. Note that if the wire is only this length, it will not be able to shift off to the right or left, and will have to break one square into smaller pieces.</sup></sup>

**wires** can be oriented as needed.

#### **bend-gate**: Bending a **wire**

[image]       [image]

<sup><sup>**Left:** Wire-frame view. **Right:** Union view.</sup></sup>

Note the use of the **4X3-gadget**. It is used to fix the red lead to odd length.

Following are the two possible **minimal-square-partition-states** of the bend:

[image]         [image]

<sup><sup>**Left and right:**Two possible **minimal-square-square-partition-states** of a bending wire.</sup></sup>

The gate can be oriented as needed. Obviously, this gate can be mirrored to work for the other direction.

#### Skewing a **wire**

It is easy to shift a wire over. Wireframe illustration:

[image]

### **named-value-gate**

A **named-value-gate** is essentially an endpoint as a gate with one wire contact:

[image]

#### **odd-skip-gate**: Odd skipping a **wire**

Sometimes it is inconvenient to only have odd-length wires. For example:

[image]

As you can see, that little bit of extension is a bit annoying. Here is a corresponding solution, using the **4X3-gate**:

[image]

So, turning this into a gate, we get the **odd-skip-gate** (in wireframe):

[image]

The gate can be oriented as needed.

#### **twist-gate**: Twisting a **wire**

Somtimes you get the red and black **i-wires** on the wrong sides for use with a **gate**. In this case, a **twist-gate** is provided, to twist the red and black **i-wires** to the opposite sides.

Wireframe illustration:

[image]

Convince yourself it works:

[image]         [image]

<sup><sup>Start from $A$, follow the push-arrows, everything else should be forced and consistent.</sup></sup>

The gate can be oriented as needed.

#### **split-gate**: Splitting a **wire**

Splitting a wire, wireframe:

[image]

Convince yourself that it works:

[image]

<sup><sup>**Figure:**Start from $A$, follow the push-arrows. Everything should be forced and consistent.</sup></sup>

[image]

<sup><sup>**Figure:**Start from $A$, follow the push-arrows. Everything should be forced and consistent.</sup></sup>

**Note:** Every wire coming in and out of the splitter **absolutely must** connect to an endpoint somewhere, in order to maintain the invariant. Alternatively, you can add endpoints to each of the pairs of leads of the splitter.

The gate can be oriented as needed.

### **not-gate**

The not gate takes a wire and outputs a wire that has the reverse implications. It is basically a **twist-gate**, except that it relabels the colorings of the wires. The **not-gate** looks like this:

[image]

And a view of the two possible states:

[image]          [image]

The gate can be oriented as needed.

### **clause-gate**

For the **clause-gate**, we first introduce the **clause-gadget**:

[image]

<sup>**Left to right:** **1** **clause-gadget**. **2-4:** $3$ different **minimal-square-partition-states**.</sup>

This is what the gate looks like:

[image]

We can demonstrate the different states of this gate (explanation underneath all $3$ illustrations):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Explanation:

2. Start at the **clause-gadget** and follow the arrows.
3. Non-arrow-lines mean that it is part of a circuit, but it is not forced into a state by the gate.
4. The state of the **clause-gadget** forces one of the endpoints to be valued **true**.

As you can see, at least one of the inputs will have to be valued as **true**. This is exactly what a $3\text{-CNF}$ clause requires.

The gate can be oriented as needed.

### Reduction

Let $\Phi(\mathbf x)$ be a $\text{Planar-}3\text{-SAT}$ formula, where

$$\Phi\left(\mathbf x\right)={\huge\wedge}_i^n C_i,\\
C=\left\{(x_j \vee x_k \vee x_l)\right\}
$$

A visual aid (original source: [Terrain Guarding is NP-Hard (PDF)](http://www.siam.org/proceedings/soda/2010/SODA10_128_kingj.pdf), reproduced in tikz):

[image]

Then:

1. For each variable $x_i\in\mathbf x$, place two **named-variable-gates** next to each-other,  name one of them $x_i$ and the other $\neg x_i$.
2. Connect the gates to each-other with a **not-gate**, so that they logically negate each-other's values.
3. Place the variables' gates' polygons at their locations in the planar-embedding.
4. For each clause, place a **clause-gate** at the clause's location in the planar-embedding.
5. Using the gates described above, connect all the variables to their clauses.
6. Run a **minimum-square-paritioning-algorithm** on the resulting union of the all of gate's polygons (the entire circuit).
7. If the algorithm returns the sum of all the gate's **minimal-square-partition-state** sizes (subtracting for shared-corners) then it is satisfiable. If it is not satisfiable, it will force a constrained gadget to split into smaller squares, thus increasing the number of squares required to partition the circuit.

### Why it works

- Each gadget has a **minimal-square-partition-state** size; that is, a **minimal-square-partition** of that gadget is a certain size.
- Some gadgets have several states with this size; each of these states are valid **minimal-square-partitions**.
- When gadgets are combined only in the corners, the sum of the **minimal-square-partition-states** of the gadgets is *still the **minimUM-square-partition-state** of the union of them; you can see this intuitively: joining at the corner does not give ample space for a square to expand/connect with a square from another gadget.
- While combining gadgets at the corner does not decrease the **total minimum-square-partition size**, it *does* relate and constrain the gadgets with each-other.
- With the gates shown above, you can constrain the states enough, so that if the logical formula is unsatisfiable, then one or more gadets will have to break into even smaller squares, and increase the **minimum-square-partition size**.

#### graph sources

- [squaretilings1.tex](https://gist.github.com/realazthat/b470ec7e3d3bb96453c4#file-squaretilings1-tex) ([writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/read/dnnyhhcjgyvb))
- [squaretilings2.tex](https://gist.github.com/realazthat/b470ec7e3d3bb96453c4#file-squaretilings2-tex)  ([writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/read/jwxnxgfybgnk))
- [clausegate.tex](https://gist.github.com/realazthat/b470ec7e3d3bb96453c4#file-clausegate-tex) ([writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/read/zpddrtfzymnj))

You can also see larger images by removing the "s", "m", "l", suffixes of the imgur urls. For example, You can see a larger image of this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CKlGs.jpg by going to 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CKlG.jpg. Notice the missing "s" before the `.jpg`.

Comment: Wow, that's absolutely impressive. Unfortunately, I am not smart enough to check the reduction, but I take your word for it :) Thanks!

Comment: So, the situation in tiling is the opposite of the situation in covering: in covering, square-covering is polynomial and rectangle-covering is NP-hard, while in tiling, square-covering is NP-hard and rectangle covering is polynomial.

Comment: Some followup questions to try and prove that the gadgets I use are indeed minimally squared: [How to prove that the minimum square partition of a 3X2 rectangle has 3 squares](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16809/2755) | [What is the minimum square partition of an almost-square rectangle?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16826/2755) | [Minimum square partitions for 4x3 and 5x4 rectangles](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/560870/39567).

Answer (score 8):

An old paper I coauthored establishes that the covering problem is polynomial for a polygon without holes, and NP-complete with holes. We showed that a key underlying graph is chordal.
Please note: the algorithm is polynomial in the number $N$ of unit squares in the polygon,
$O(N^{3/2})$.

> "Covering orthogonal polygons with squares."
>   L. J. Aupperle and H. E. Conn and J. M. Keil and Joseph O'Rourke.
>   *Proc. 26th Allerton Conf. Commun. Control Comput.*, pp. 97-106, 1988.
>   ([link to download PDF scan](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/papers.php#293))

However, the resulting covering may include squares that overlap.  You are looking for a tiling, where squares are not permitted to overlap, so your problem is not quite the same.

Comment: lol I was half-way through a formulation :(. Very interesting though! Welcome to cs.SE.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this paper allows the squares to overlap (i.e. it is a covering problem). I am interested in the case where the squares are not allowed to overlap (i.e. it is a partitioning / tiling problem).

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: Oh, I am sorry, I didn't read your question carefully.

Comment: Oh then I shall continue :D