# What is the minimum square partition of an almost-square rectangle?

Tags: computational-geometry, tiling

This question is motivated by an older question about [tiling an orthogonal polygon with squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16661/2755).
It is a generalisation of my former question about [how to prove that the minimum square partition of a 3X2 rectangle has 3 squares](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/16809/2755)).

Let:

- An *almost-square-rectangle* be a rectangle that has a width  $w$ and height $h=w-1$.
- A *square partitioning* be a covering by non-overlapping squares; the entire rectangle must be covered, all the squares must be disjoint.
- A *minimum-square-partitioning* be a *square partitioning*, for which is no square partitioning that is made of a lesser number of squares.

Illustration:

[image]

<sup>**Top row:** The **almost-square-rectangles** of widths $3$, $4$ and $5$. **Bottom row:** Are these **miminum-square-partitions** of their corresponding rectangles?</sup>

My question is now:

> What is the minimum-square-partitioning of an almost-square-rectangle?
>
> Can we prove ${\rm M{\small IN}S{\small QUARES}}(R_{w,h=w-1})=w$?

<sub>Note a follow-up question, [Minimum square partitions for 4x3 and 5x4 rectangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/560870/39567).</sub>

Comment: Is it just me, or is ${\rm M{\small IN}S{\small QUARES}}(R_{w,h})=\frac {\max (w, h)}{\gcd (w, h)}$?

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė with $R_{5,3}$ that gives me $5$, but I think you can cover a $R_{5,3}$ with a $1\cdot R_{3,3} + 1\cdot R_{2,2} + 2\cdot R_{1,1} = 4\text{ squares}$.

Comment: Right, I was silly. Still, the covering follows euclidean algorithm. The number of squares is the number of steps. I think...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė yeah I agree it is related to what I *intuitively* know is the minimum-square-partition; with some thought one can come up with a formula for general $R_{w,h}$. I don't just want a general formula; I want a proof (a proof along with a general formula would be nice though).

Comment: Please format your questions with a lighter hand. Formatting should be functional in supporting the reader; you used a sledgehammer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[A similar question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44524/minimum-tiling-of-a-rectangle-by-squares) was asked on Mathoverflow. The commenters mentioned a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0097316596901041#) of Kenyon, which shows that the minimum number of squares required to tile a $w \times (w-1)$ rectangle is $\Theta(\log w)$. See also a related [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X08004780?np=y) of Walters.

---

You can tile a $(4t+7) \times (4t+6)$ rectangle using only $t+5$ squares (for $t \geq 0$).

[image: Tiling a 6 by 7 rectangle][image: Tiling a 10 by 11 rectangle]
[image: Tiling a 14 by 15 rectangle][image: Tiling a 18 by 19 rectangle]

Comment: Nice! Do I see room for recursion here? In the bottom right corner there is a $(2t+4)\times (2t+2)$ rectangle tiled with $t+2$ squares, in a way similar to the original solution, but scaled to a $2 \times 2$ grid. (sorry hard to express what I mean.)

Comment: Have a look at Kenyon's paper - it gives an algorithm which tiles a $w \times (w-1)$ rectangle with $O(\log w)$ squares.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus what about those specific rectangles I drew above? Are those minimally tiled?

Comment: That's probable, and should be provable using some case analysis. For more sophisticated methods, see Kenyon's paper, which uses the electrical resistance method.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I asked this as a [follow-up](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/560870/39567) on math.SE.

Comment: Another followup: [What is the first w such that a rectangle, Rw×w−1 is minimally-square-partitioned by less than w squares.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/570071/39567).